# Is there need for a migrate path to LL.SE?

Tags: discussion, migration

Today, LL.SE (Language Learning) opened to private beta. As a graduated site, we can have migrate paths, so when public beta opens over on LL, is there a need for a default path to there?

Are there many questions on this site that would be better for a more general language acquisition site?

Comment: I would leave a comment on the question, recommending the OP ask on another site.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Stack Exchange does not open user migration paths to beta sites. They are expected to grow and decide what they want to be on their own terms.

[Source: Tim Post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/178463/315433)

Comment: I thought it was just from beta sites. Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 1):

Considering that [the site is described as](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/82841/language-learning) *site for students, teachers, polyglots, and anyone interested in the techniques of second-language acquisition*, I would say there isn't the need of a migration path for that site. If somebody is asking in our site a question that better suites that site, we could leave a comment in that question.

Keep in mind that migration paths are not created until the site for which you want to establish a migration path doesn't come out from the beta phase.